# Uploading PSD files not possible

Tags: assets

I have created an Asset field type and have the "restrict file types" option not checked.

When I attempt to upload a file with extension .PSD i get the message `Upload failed for 020516_Action-Buttons_Desktop.psd. The error message was: “Error uploading the file: This file type is not allowed”`

Is there a setting someplace else thats preventing this?

I also tried checking the restrict option and selecting "Photoshop file". But this also did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the `psd` extension to `extraAllowedFileExtensions` in your config file.

```
'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'psd'
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#extraAllowedFileExtensions